# Excel VBA: concatenate formula with if condition

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, formula

I am trying to use the below coding to concatenate the cells based on criteria.. It throws me an syntax error. Can you please help me to correct this code or do I need to use a different method.

Request:

[image]

Code:

```
Sub Conc()
Dim lastrow As Range
Dim str As String


With Worksheets("sheet1")
lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("F2").Select

Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(B2="aaa@to.com",CONCATENATE(E2," -",MID(A2,FIND("SECN",A2),14)),IF(B2<>"aaa@to.com",CONCATENATE(MID(A2,FIND("SECN",A2),14)," - ",C2)))"
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Within the formula, you must **double-up** on the **double quotes**.

Comment: @Gary's Student - It says Object variable or with block variable not set :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to to double on your `"` inside the formula string.

Second, you need to fully qualify all your `Cells`, `Rows.Count` and `Range` objects nested inside your `With Worksheets("sheet1")` statement.

Third, there's no need to `Select` the `Range` before setting the `Formula` to it.

```
With Worksheets("sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(B2=""aaa@to.com"",CONCATENATE(E2,"" - "",MID(A2,FIND("" SECN"",A2),14)),IF(B2<>""aaa@to.com"",CONCATENATE(MID(A2,FIND(""SECN"",A2),14),"" - "",C2)))"
End With
```

Comment: Object variable or with block variable not set error :(

Comment: @Kelvin  on what line ?

Comment: macro is not working. It throws that error directly.

Comment: @Kelvin  u r not really helping me help you. Run in debug mode and see what line the code stops

Comment: Sorry.. its with the formula line
  .Range("F2:F" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(B2=""aaa@to.com"",CONCATENATE(E2,"" - "",MID(A2,FIND(""SECN"",A2),14)),IF(B2<>""aaa@to.com"",CONCATENATE(MID(A2,FIND(""SECN"",A2),14),"" - "",C2)))"

Comment: @Kelvin  what value are you getting for LastRow ?

Comment: Thanks for your support.. the issue was the last row and its been resolved now.. I will post the updated code. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code for.. issue was with the lastrow definition and thanks @Gary's Student and @Shai Rado for your valuable suggestion on the formula..

```
Sub Conc()

    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
         lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("F2:F" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(B2=""aaa@to.com"",CONCATENATE(E2,"" - "",MID(A2,FIND(""SECN"",A2),14)),IF(B2<>""aaa@to.com"",CONCATENATE(MID(A2,FIND(""SECN"",A2),14),"" - "",C2)))"
    End With
End Sub
```